# Mysql not allowing " ' "

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns and update them through excel user form and all are varchar (255). when I try to enter the character ' I get syntax error, mysql doesn't accept it... What am I doing wrong here, do I need to change datatype

Update: I figured that the problem is not with MySQL (obviously :) ) but my code to update the table.

```
Dim sq As String
sq = "UPDATE sample.`nov-21` SET `Site work being carried out`='" & sitecombo.value & "',`Group`='" & eqgrp.value & "',`Description`='" & desc.value & "',`T Number`='" & tn.value & "', WHERE sample.`nov-21`.`ID`= " & Me.IDnum & ";"
```

Comment: Danny we aren't mind readers. Spill the beans with your code.

Comment: use backslash like `"\'"`

Comment: This looks like you have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code. What language is this - VB Script?

Comment: Visual Basic with MySQL query

Answer (score 1):

Escape `'` with `\` or another `'`: `'O''Malley'` or `'O\'Malley'`

When you write `'O'Malley'`, MySQL read string literal `'O'` followed by name `Malley` (which is not recognized) and a `'` with no meaning, hence the syntax error.

Comment: Thank you mate, you just cleared the reason why I getting them error. I just update my question sorry about that.I am updating through excel form. I can't expect my users to add a \ everytime they try to add '

Comment: Then use `prepared statement` in the language you are using to run the MySQL queries. Otherwise, you'll get SQL injections.

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that.

Comment: It depends on the language you use to do the MySQL. You do you do your queries? [edit your question if that's long to say]